# Xpath correction check please

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

### Given XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
     <sensor-system>
        <velocity>120.00</velocity> <!-- km/h --> 
        <temperature location="inside">24.6</temperature> 
         <temperature location="outside">-12.5</temperature>

     <seats>

     <seat location="front">
          <id>1</id> 
          <temperature>32.5</temperature> 
          <heating-is-on/>

      </seat> 
    <seat location="back">

      <id>2</id>
      <temperature>23.5</temperature>
   </seat>

</seats>
  </sensor-system>
```

### Required XML path:

Give an absolute XPATH that identifies all front seats with a temperature greater than or equal to 20.0 and less than or equal to 30.0 degrees celsius.

### My solution please check:

Is this correct :

```
/sensor-system/seats[temperature>=20 | temperature <=30]/seat[@location="front"]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You xpath is not quite correct because it is expecting the **temperature** element to be a child of the **seats** element, when you should be checking the **seat** element.

EDIT: Another thing to point out that in your original xpath, you are using the '|' operator, which is the union operator, and which takes two node-sets as arguments. So it won't work in your example, as your arguments are actually 'conditions'.

Try this instead

```
/sensor-system/seats/seat[temperature >= 20][temperature <= 30][@location = "front"]
```

Note, if you were using this in XSLT, you might have to escape the < here

```
/sensor-system/seats/seat[temperature >= 20][temperature &lt;= 30][@location = "front"]
```

Although you may prefer to do this

```
/sensor-system/seats/seat[temperature >= 20][not(temperature > 30)][@location = "front"]
```

Comment: +1, good answer. @OP, note you can also say `[A and B and C]` as an alternative to `[A][B][C]`.

Comment: +1, though note that in the general case where there might be more than one `temperature` element, the two tests `[temperature <= 30]` and `[not(temperature > 30)]` don't mean the same thing - the first is true if there is _any_ temperature child less than or equal to 30, the second only if _all_ temperature children are less than or equal to 30.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this :

```
/sensor-system/seats/seat[@location="front"]/temperature >=20 and /sensor-system/seats/seat[@location="front"]/temperature <= 30
```

This will be `true` for `[@location="back"]` and `false` for `[@location="front"]`

Comment: The request was for an XPath that *identifies* all qualifying seats, whereas I believe your XPath expression will just return a boolean saying whether qualifying seats exist (and even that won't be quite right). Also your last sentence seems to have the `true`/`false` reversed?